# Discord.py adding reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to make a poll command, bot will send a message like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlGaw.png and add two reactions to this: `:one:` and `:two:`, here's my actual code:

```
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx, quest, opt1, opt2):
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x29db4d)
    embed.add_field(name=quest, value=f":one: - {opt1}, :two: - {opt2}", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.add_reaction('one')
    await ctx.add_reaction('two')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding reactions, you're supposed to either use the `unicode` (standard emoji's), or `name:id` (alternatively `<:name:id>`) for custom emoji's. In your case, `:one:` and `:two:` are both standard emoji's.

Also, I assume you want to add your reactions to the actual embed you sent, not the command calling it. `Messageable.send()` returns the `discord.Message` instance of the message it sent, so you can use `message = ctx.send(...)` for that.

```py
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx, quest, opt1, opt2):
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x29db4d)
    embed.add_field(name=quest, value=f":one: - {opt1}, :two: - {opt2}", inline=True)
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    await message.add_reaction("2️⃣")
```

Comment: You can get the raw emoji by sending it in discord using `\` before it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I didn't get any error, just bot doesn't add any reactions. To the message

Comment: Does it have the permissions to add reactions in that channel? I just tested this code & it does in fact work. Can you try it out in a DM with your bot?

Comment: It has permissions, i tried in dm, but still nothing. Oops, sorry it's my fault. Thanks for help and response!